# How to etermine if a file is appended or outright changed

Tags: java, text-files, fileinputstream

I'm wondering the best method for my program to determine if a file has been appended or completely changed.

What I am currently doing is using a LogIOThread I wrote that is using a FileInputStream.avail to check if a file has been appended. If so, I am appending to a non-editable JTextArea (actually a modified JTextArea with variable scroll features). My end-game was to have a autoscrolling JTextArea that is basically scrolling a log4j outputted logfile. This is working great for me right now. I'd like to adapt this to a non-log files.

What I would like to add to the LogIOThread is a monitor that will check if the file contents changed rather than just have new appended text. The first use case I am trying to solve is the file gets rewritten mid run. At the most basic level I figured I could use this function to reload my JTextArea close and reopen the FileInputStream, and start over if the file get overwritten.

I figured while I was doing that I might want to make it more robust to handle the second use case of mid-file insertions, like a properties file change. I figured I could get the textArea to do a line replace if I can figure out if a line changed.

I have a requirement (not set by me) to use Java6, so some of the new nio FileWatcher's are no good for me. Notifiers in general seem counter productive as I'm catching appends via FileInputStream. This also led me to discount other libs such as Commons and jnotify. I could be wrong though, and maybe FileInputStream.avail is not the best way for me anymore.

My first thought was that I could store the file size, and check if it drastically changed (to a value less than stored). Since a new created log file would need a fresh textArea, this doesn't seem to bad, and solves my first use case. This would not work for the second use case of a specific value change in the file. It also might be problematic for a file that gets recreated with a consistent size while my IOThread is sleeping, although I doubt it's likely.

My second thought was that I could continually check the file modified time, and if there is no appendable text, I would reread the file and do a line comparison? I would need to do this anyway if I'm going to change a line in the textArea unless I reload it every time. This seems horribly inefficient though.

Any suggestions? I'm not opposed to changing how the LogIOThread works if there is a suggestion to get new text and changes with something better than an avail + file modification check combo.

Answer (score 1):

If the file size decreases it has certainly been overwritten. However it may also be overwritten with something as large or larger, so the converse does not hold.

Don't use available() as a surrogate for File.length(). See the Javadoc. That's not what it's for.

Comment: I agree on both counts. 

I think I've thrown out the file size decrease as valid to satisfy both use cases - <EDIT> - actually I see that it wouldn't satisfay either use case...

I was using available to check for appended text (not for changes or length). Is that still improper or is there a better way to check for appended text in a FileInputStream?

Comment: @user837631 Yes there is, and I have already mentioned it in my answer. available() tells you how many bytes can be read *without blocking.* It has no necessary relationship with the total length of the input.

Comment: @ EJP Are you saying use File.length() - last length to read the next number of bytes that has been appended since that last time I checked? (in lieu of using available() )

Answer (score 0):

How about creating an intermediate `OutputStream` that reads the log data, makes it available to the `JTextField` and then routes that data to the file?